# how to retain header using AWK

Tags: awk

How can I print the header from data1 while running this comparison of two files data1 and data2 matching on column 2? My code only prints data lines.  The headers are named differently and so I choose to use column position

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR {a[$2]=$0; next}; $2 in a {print a[$2]}' /data1 /data2  > /data3.txt
```

Comment: See [ask] and post the missing [mcve].

Comment: I think $0 is creating problem here, $0 is used to print complete file if you can share sample input data, that would be easy to answer your question.

 I was able to print the header line without NR==1. using below command - 

 awk ' NR==FNR { location[$1] = $NF; next }; $8 in location {print $0, location[$NF]}' dept emp

EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM     DEPTNO LOC
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20-FEB-81       1600        300         30 CHICAGO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==1; FNR==NR{a[$2]=$0; next} ...
```

will print the first line of the first file.  If you want to skip processing replace with `NR==1{print; next}`.